# How do I remove the branding from tinymce? (Where it says 'Powered by tinymce')

Tags: tinymce

How can I remove the branding from the bottom of the tinymce editor where it says 'Powered by TinyMCE'?

Comment: @Olaf As noted in the SOCVR chatroom: They wouldn't have added a "branding: false" parameter if it was legally questionable, and it's completely programming related.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on here. I just documented this feature of the tinymce editor as I had trouble finding the setting when I wanted it. Not sure why this was closed or why people think this might be rude. The option is documented on tinymce's website https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Initialize the editor as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#tinymce',
    branding: false
});
```

With the react integration you can initialize as follows:

```
<Editor     
  apiKey={TinyMCE_API_Key}
  initialValue={initialValue}
  init={{
    branding: false
  }} 
    
  onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
/>
```

Comment: With "branding: false" the space taken up by this message will still stay reserved for status messages. You can remove this status bar with "statusbar: false". Disadvantage is that this will also remove the handle that allows you to drag the textarea to a bigger size.

Comment: @user2587656 Thankfully, this isn't the case anymore in 2022, the space gets removed automatically with branding: false

Answer (score 0):

For TinyMCE Version 6

Initialize the Editor as shown

By adding `branding:false` we can remove the branding

```
<Editor     
  apiKey={TinyMCE_API_Key}
  initialValue={initialValue}
  init={{
    branding: false
  }} 
    
  onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
/>
```